# Unequal div heights

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I want to make unequal images heights and keep the layout the same on resize without changing the aspect ratio of the image on here is what i want to do :
https://i.ibb.co/nkSXJ4f/Screen-Shot-2019-04-12-at-6-32-32-AM.png

I know this is ease with css grid but i think i can make my code more simple since the layout is not complicated

What i've tried

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.card {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2.6668rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.medium {
  width: 65%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.small {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main class="grid">
  <a href="" class="card medium">
    <figcaption class="caption">project title</figcaption>
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554565166-cafee0896506?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="" class="card small">
    <figcaption class="caption">Kettle</figcaption>
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554565166-cafee0896506?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>
</main>
```

Comment: Why this fixed height to both of these divs when you want the whole image??
what exactly are you expecting??

Comment: You didn't get my point to be more clear check the image that i posted and tell me how would you make a layout like that

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. The images resize nicely and they keep their aspect ratios, so what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: i want to constrain the height and width of the image while resizing, example :https://preview.themeforest.net/item/airtifact-portfolio-creative-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/21952418

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.card {
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  height:100vh;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.medium {
  width: 65%;
  margin-right: 5%;
    float:left
}

.small {
  width: 25%;
  float:left
}
.card-image { height:100%; }

.card-image img {
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<main class="grid">
  <a href="" class="card medium">
    <figcaption class="caption">project title</figcaption>
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554565166-cafee0896506?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="" class="card small">
    <figcaption class="caption">Kettle</figcaption>
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554565166-cafee0896506?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>
</main>
```